# How might these anarchic 'olm-men' originate?

Tags: evolution, politics

The olm-men are a group of troglomorphic stygofauns found deep in the earth. Uniquely, they have no king, a court, or even an elected parliament; they have no leaders at all. All members of their society are treated equally regardless of their appearance, physical prowess, or mental traits

The problem is where they came from. They originally were humanlike mammalian creatures that had strong limbs and needed air, before they were forced underground and became weak, water-breathing amphibians. However, their anarchic non-government came about before this and was retained throughout their evolution to their olmy forms

How could these events happen as I have described? To explain, I'm not asking what evolutionary pressures could cause this change, instead, I'd like to ask about what social and/or political ideals could allow these pressures to guide their evolution

Comment: Since when political ideals drive evolution?

Comment: @L.Dutch Politics decides what happens in a society, including which genotypes can and cannot reproduce

Comment: (1) Natural evolution operates on the geological time scale. Politics operates on the human life timescale, or, at most and only rarely, historical timescale. There has never been a human political structure which has endured for *maybe*, being generous, two thousand years. (2) When you say that "all members of their society are treated equally" this is a very weak requirement. *Most* human political structures have this feature. For example, czarist Russia and the Ottoman empire qualify -- all members of society were treated equally bad, as they were all slaves of the czar or of the sultan.

Comment: @IchthysKing --- Not if everyone is their own king...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is clearly "tell me a story about...". Voting to close, as this is story based.

Comment: Stop using incomprehensible phrases like "troglomorphic stygofauns". You will get better answers if you try to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

## Just like Regular Olms

Regular olms look like this:

[image]

Olm people look like this:

[image]

Essentially the same.

What would force a creature to evolve into an olm-like form? Why whatever happened to the olms, of course.

They used to be non-olms. Then they found a cave with a hole in the foodchain and evolved to fill it. The long thin body with breathy skin, no pigment, and tiny limbs help them live there. The lack of government is there for the same reason real olms have no government. They are mostly solitary. They do not live in groups or need a social structure.

Their interaction is 95% go away please (they are polite of course) and 5% mate with me.

Comment: Olms had no society to help eachother, whereas the olm-men did. How would the environmental pressures affect the olm-men when they help eachother and lack any government

Comment: @IchthysKing There is little food in the caves. The olm men spread out and eventually become asocial.

Answer (score 0):

#### Timescale Discontinuity Error in 420

The connundrum can be relatively easily solved by understanding the development of Olmmen in two parallel continua, one of which is broken. The first continuum is the physiological, the unbroken one, and the one you're not interested in. Suffice to say that something similar to a human-like creature evolved into something looking a bit like an olm.

Since you're interested in "social and political ideals", I think we first have to come to terms with the time scales involved. Very likely, the direction of progress you're interested in will take 10s of millions of years. I find it very unlikely that any kind of recogniseably human culture will last anywhere near that long. I also think that human culture drives evolution in ways that Nature does not, and would very likely work against the kind of physiological trend you're looking for.

Therefore, I would solve the issue by having the humanoid ancestors who went into the underworld *actually lose* their human culture. As Daron points out, simply in order for anyone to survive in the caves, with so little food, a lot of people are gonna die real quick. If any survive at all you'll be lucky, and those that do simply won't be able to maintain much in the way of human culture.

Eventually the humanoids will forget that they were once human at all and thus become free for Nature to begin guiding their evolution again. Skip ahead 10 million years and some set of conditions allows for these neo-amphibian descendants of something human-like to switch over to culture driven evolution again.

Since these new people will now be largely solitary & generally antisocial, it stands to reason that any culture and language they (re)evolve will be based on the new reality. They won't form governments of any kind, let alone the concept of "anarchy", simply because each Olmman is her own state if you will. Each individual is the boss and sole citizen. Any government-like construct that they develop will likely be nothing more than a rule-set designed to allow strongly individualistic people to interact when it's not time to mate.

It's not an anarchy because there is really no archy to stand against. This quasi-government could evolve some 5000 to 10000 years before the present, and would probably remain quite stable as it is literally an extension of their now instinctual behaviours.

Comment: You can still have higherarchical structures without government.